# how to read an amazon SNS response in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an app that records a video, and then transcodes it via Amazon Elastic transcoder. When it is done transcoding, amazon SNS sends back a file that says the video is done transcoding, along with information about the video (filename, duration, etc.) as a POST request to my users profile page. This is sent back as a text/plain content-type, but in the format of a JSON file.

All of this is working correctly (from an Amazon point of view), but how can I capture (in the rails app) the content of the SNS file being sent?

EDIT: Amazon Response (to /*/profile, response code 404 Not Found)

`{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "6e311e3a-b0ed-5124-8578-4e72843d35b1",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:224636007242:soundstream_video_transcoding_complete",
  "Subject" : "Amazon Elastic Transcoder has finished transcoding job 1473131144092-6ti9g6.",
  "Message" : "{\n  \"state\" : \"COMPLETED\",\n  \"version\" : \"2012-09-25\",\n  \"jobId\" : \"1473131144092-6ti9g6\",\n  \"pipelineId\" : \"1466964609042\",\n  \"input\" : {\n    \"key\" : \"45423012/97061c7f-465f-46ec-80dd-6a92b474fd58/archive.mp4\",\n    \"frameRate\" : \"auto\",\n    \"resolution\" : \"auto\",\n    \"aspectRatio\" : \"auto\",\n    \"interlaced\" : \"auto\",\n    \"container\" : \"mp4\"\n  },\n  \"outputs\" : [ {\n    \"id\" : \"1\",\n    \"presetId\" : \"1469647121114-zvgtx6\",\n    \"key\" : \"transcoded/video-97061c7f-465f-46ec-80dd-6a92b474fd58.mp4\",\n    \"thumbnailPattern\" : \"thumbnails/97061c7f-465f-46ec-80dd-6a92b474fd58/video-{count}\",\n    \"status\" : \"Complete\",\n    \"duration\" : 10,\n    \"width\" : 640,\n    \"height\" : 480\n  } ]\n}",
  "Timestamp" : "2016-09-06T03:05:52.728Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
}`

Comment: What have you tried? We can't just write the code for you; you have to have a go yourself first.

Comment: what is the content of the AWS response?

Comment: @maxpleaner edited to include response

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse(response["Message"])` and seeing if it contains your needed data? Not clear on what the missing info is.

Comment: yeah, that gives me this: "no implicit conversion of nil into String"

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check here: 1) what is the SNS topic subscribed to? Go in the AWS consoles, lookup the topic by ARN and see the endpoint(s) that are subscribed. Is this what you are expecting? 2) Make sure that your endpoint is public and that you have a route that maps to the endpoint. The 404 most likely means that your rails app does not know how to handle the route and/or does not have a resource mapped to it.

Once you have 1) and 2) you need to parse the message to json and inspect the fields you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 23, 2023, Amazon SNS now supports custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the announcement post: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

You will have to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

You can set the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute by calling either the `Subscribe` or the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` API action:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html

CloudFormation is supported as well. Cheers!